# Can I integrate APP ID with tools like Jenkins, SonarQube, Jira and Gitlab?

Tags: ibm-appid

I want to setup DevOps tool chain with a common Authentication and Authorization. Can I authenticate tools like Gitlab, Jenkins, SonarQube and Nexs with App ID?. I need to enable single sign on across all these tools

I tried APP ID looks like it supports only OIDC. Some of my tools support SAML, OIDC and Ldap, can APP Id support integrating multiple tools with different supported authentication mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would like users to sign-in before they are using Gitlab, Jenkins, SonarQube and Nexs? And if so, who are those users i.e. what is the user repository?

Or do you want to configure App ID as in https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/how-to-configure-ibm-cloud-app-id-from-the-toolchain

Comment: I have diverse user base for my tools. Some are w3id, some are from OKTA and few are from Google ID. The tools Jenkins, Gitlab and Sonar does not support multi authentication mechanism. So I want to enable authentication for all the tools using APP ID and I want to configure APP ID with other third party authentication providers. Is this possible with APP ID?

Answer (score 0):

App ID is OAuth2 and OpenID Connect (OIDC) compliant. Any tool or application that knows how to integrate with OAuth2/OIDC providers for authentication and SSO can leverage App ID for this purpose.

Comment: I need users from multiple SAML providers to login to my tool. In the APP ID console  I currently see option to configure only one SAML provider. Can APP ID integrate with multiple SAML provider?